# Finding the closest vector to an observation

Tags: optimization, estimation, mean-square-error

I have a collection of vectors (a codebook  in hand) which are presented within a matrix $A$

$$ A = [ a (\theta_1), \,  a (\theta_2), \, a (\theta_3), \, a (\theta_4), \,\cdots]$$

We have obtained from a certain observation some vector, lets call it $a(\phi)$, which is not from any of the vectors in matrix $A$, our aim however is to find a vector from A that is closest and best resembles $a(\phi)$

I have thought of couple of solutions

1-$i^*$= $\arg \min_i$ $|| a(\theta_i) - a (\phi) ||^2$

2-$i^*$=  $\arg \min_i \mathbb{E} [ |e_i|^2]$ where $e_i=a(\theta_i) - a (\phi) $  (minimum mean square error estimate)

3- $i^*  = \arg \max_i |a(\theta_i)a (\phi)|$

Which of these solutions is the best, are they all the same? Any reference on how to handle such problems?

Comment: The first two are the same,, the third is different.  As to "best" you will have to tell us how you are judging that.

Comment: you have not defined what you mean by close, and are therefore asking for a "best definition" of close without giving any inkling of what you intend to do after you find your "close" vector. Please provide more information.

Comment: thank you, can you please explain to me what further information is needed from me?

Comment: @henry what do you intend to do with your close vector?

Comment: by close I mean equal...